# Prolog, return only smallest result

Tags: prolog, shortest-path, minimum

For example my output is like this

```
?- sroute(india,england,X).
X = 2481 ;
X = 3438 ;
X = 1931 ;
X = 3762 ;
X = 3840 ;
X = 1922 ;
X = 2668 ;
X = 2677 ;
X = 4184 ;
X = 3227 ;
X = 2000 ;
false.
```

I'm assuming I found all routes and their distances(recursively) in my code and they are all true, but i want to see only "X = 1922 ." when i ask sroute(india,england,X). How i can do this, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`setof/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) to get a sorted set and take only the first element of the resulting set:

```
setof(X, sroute(india,england,X), [Min|_]).
```